# jdbc spring opentracing close connection during transaction

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, opentracing

I use opentracing and all my jdbc Connections are wrapped in TracingConnection proxy.
The problem arises when I use method `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate#queryForStream(java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>, org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<T>)` during transaction

This method executes method `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#doReleaseConnection` and explain, if Connection is transactional or not

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#doReleaseConnection
```

To do this, the method compares Connection from ConnectionHolder and passed Connection, with `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#connectionEquals` method

```
private static boolean connectionEquals(ConnectionHolder conHolder, Connection passedInCon) {
    if (!conHolder.hasConnection()) {
        return false;
    }
    Connection heldCon = conHolder.getConnection();
    // Explicitly check for identity too: for Connection handles that do not implement
    // "equals" properly, such as the ones Commons DBCP exposes).
    return (heldCon == passedInCon || heldCon.equals(passedInCon) ||
            getTargetConnection(heldCon).equals(passedInCon));
}
```

The problem is that connection from ConnectionHolder is instance of
`io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingConnection` and passedInCon is instance of `HikariProxyConnection wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection`. If I unwrap Connection from ConnectionHolder, I can see that it's equals to passedInCon, but passedInCon doesn't wrapping into TracingConnection.

I was figuring out why passedInCon is not an instance of TracingConnection. PassedInCon is taken from preparedStatement which in turn is created here `io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingConnection#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)`
In that method Connection is instance of `HikariProxyConnection wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection` and further it is not wrapped in TracingConnection.

What solutions are there so that the Connection is wrapped into TracingConnection here and when compared they are the same? Or other approaches to not closing the connection during a transaction with opentracing enabled?